# How to enable play-querydsl plugin in Play 2.3?

Tags: java, playframework, sbt, playframework-2.3

I'm trying to use the [play-querydsl](https://github.com/CedricGatay/play-querydsl) plugin with Play 2.3 with no success. I know that the plugin system has changed in Play 2.3, but I'm wondering if there is any way to use an old Play 2.2 plugin with Play 2.3.

[The play-querydsl's Installation page](https://github.com/CedricGatay/play-querydsl#installation) lists the following steps to enable the plugin for Play 2.2:

```
playJavaSettings ++ QueryDSLPlugin.queryDSLSettings

val current = project.in(file(".")).configs(QueryDSLPlugin.QueryDSL)
```

However, if I understand correctly, there is no `playJavaSettings` in Play 2.3 (even though it's mentioned in [About SBT Settings](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/SBTSettings)).

Is there any way to use this plugin from Play 2.3 without changing the plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like `playJavaSettings` and `playScalaSettings` were combined into `projectSettings` in Play 2.3. This quite annoyingly has a namespace conflict with QueryDSLs `projectSettings`.

Here's a fresh new `build.sbt` for Play 2.3 Java:

```
name := """javatest2.3"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)

scalaVersion := "2.11.1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  javaEbean,
  cache,
  javaWs
)
```

To add the plugin settings, I had to use the full path of Play's `projectSettings` to avoid the namespace conflict, adding this line:

```
com.typesafe.sbt.SbtNativePackager.projectSettings ++ QueryDSLPlugin.queryDSLSettings
```

This can be shortened with an import, but whatever. Then, instead of adding the second line as stated in the docs, I chained `.configs(QueryDSLPlugin.QueryDSL)` to the already existing `root`:

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava).configs(QueryDSLPlugin.QueryDSL)
```

And it compiles.

Comment: I use a later version (3.3.4) of QueryDSL than the play-querydsl plugin, so I found that I had to put both your suggested lines after the `libraryDependencies ++` line or the compiler wouldn't find my newer QueryDSL jar file.  Once I did that, everything worked.

Answer (score 1):

Version `0.1.2` of the plugin has been released recently. With Play 2.3, enabling it is now dead simple and for the default Java project goes like:

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava, QueryDSLPlugin)
```

Please note, that `QueryDSLPlugin` prefix  is now no longer used for configuration settings.